# VectorPlot3D legend label

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I am trying to plot a 3D vector field and I want to also attach a labeled-legend to it, but it appears that `LegendLabel` is not an option for `VectorPlot3D`. How can I get around this? I want to specify the legend label as the "Magnitude" of the vector field, such as

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image] Magnitude [image]

or something akin. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> "magnitude"]]
```

[image]

Comment: So simple :) Thank you!